# How to get the records from inner query results with the MAX value

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

The results are below. I need to get the records (seller and purchaser) with the max count- grouped by purchaser (marked with yellow)

[image]

Comment: Can you share you query?

Comment: how is 2 the MAX count? I dont follow the logic.

Comment: its the max group by purchaser..

Comment: ahhh sorry, I marked the wrong one. i will fix it...

Comment: Any answers please?.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
with q as (
      <your query here>
     )
select q.*
from (select q.*,
             row_number() over (order by seller desc) as seqnum_s,
             row_number() over (order by purchaser desc) as seqnum_p
      from q
     ) q
where seqnum_s = 1 or seqnum_p = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  COUNT,seller,purchaser  FROM YourTable ORDER BY seller,purchaser DESC
```

Comment: It will not give me what I need... just order the results. I need to filter them and get only the max records

Comment: If the Query that Yahya suggested it's ok for you just add LIMIT 2 at the end and you will get the 2 records with the max  Value.

Comment: I have more records wuth more sellers. I can't take the top 2. I need it to be flexible

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T2.MaxCount,T2.purchaser,T1.Seller FROM <Yourtable> T1
Inner JOIN
(
Select  Max(Count) as MaxCount, purchaser
FROM <Yourtable>
GROUP BY Purchaser
)T2
On T2.Purchaser=T1.Purchaser AND T2.MaxCount=T1.Count
```

First you select the **Seller** from  which will give you a list of all 5 sellers. Then you write another query where you select only the **Purchaser** and the **Max(count)** grouped by **Purchaser** which will give you the two yellow-marked lines. Join the two queries on fields **Purchaser** and **Max(Count)** and add the columns from the joined table to your first query.

I can't think of a faster way but this works pretty fast even with rather large queries. You can further-by order the fields as needed.

Comment: Group by Purchaser, Seller

Comment: It will give me all the entire records. not just the yellow marked

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.